# Calling Swift async function from Objective-C

Tags: swift, objective-c, swift5

I am using the new Swift 5.5 features to create an async function:

```
@MainActor
@objc func updateStatus() async {
    /// do async stuff...
}
```

But when I try to call this method from Objective-C code, it doesn't show up in autocomplete and gives a build error if I try to build it:

```
if (@available(iOS 15.0, *)) {
     CJSubscriptionStatusCheck *backgroundStatusCheck = [[CJSubscriptionStatusCheck alloc] init];
     [backgroundStatusCheck updateStatus]; // No visible @interface for 'CJStatusCheck' declares the selector 'updateStatus'
}
```

My other swift code works fine with Objective-C so the setup is fine, but I'm not sure how the 'async' code can be used (if at all) with Objective-C. I can't find an answer to this with my research.

Thanks.

Comment: According to https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0297-concurrency-objc.md the method in Obj-C should be called `updateStatusCompletionHandler:` or something similar.

Comment: That works! The Xcode autocomplete doesn't list it in the dropdown, but it does work! If you submit it as an answer I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [SE-0297 Concurrency Interoperability with Objective-C](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0297-concurrency-objc.md) `async` methods get added `completionHandler` parameter automatically.

Therefore the method name should be something similar to `updateStatusCompletionHandler:` in Objective-C.